# Inner Join on Concat

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used this code in SQL Server to join two tables on unique values i made with concat.

My intention was to create unique values with concat function in both tables so I can join them on matching  values.

Problem is that query written in this way never never executes (like some sort of  infinite loop)

[Table inputs and result][image: 1]

```
select t1.AAA, t1.BBB, t1.XXX, t2.YYY
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on concat(t1.AAA, t1.BBB)= CONCAT(t2.AAA, t2.BBB)
```

Answer (score 1):

why concat , this way you lose benefit of optimizer & index ,

you can join on two condition :

```
select select t1.AAA, t1.BBB, t1.XXX, t2.YYY
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2
on t1.AAA= t2.AAA
and t1.BBB = t2.BBB
```

Answer (score 1):

The query that you want is:

```
select t1.AAA, t1.BBB, t1.XXX, t2.YYY
from Table1 t1 inner join
     Table2 t2
     on t1.AAA = t2.AAA and t1.BBB = t2.BBB;
```

Then, if performance is a concern, you want an index on `Table1(AAA, BBB)` or `Table2(AAA, BBB)` or both.  The columns can also be reversed in the indexes.